# Do not send keystrokes to specific program

Tags: hotkeys, keystrokes

I am using macros on my f1-f4 keys.

Can I somehow stop certain programs from receiving keystrokes from f1-f4 in case these programs have overlapping hotkeys?

OS: Windows 10
I used AHK for the Macros

Comment: Please provide more context. What operating system are you using? How did you set up the macros?